# Porting ncurses app to IOS

Tags: c++, ios, ncurses

I have several ncurses apps that I would love to run on my iPad. However, I don't know if this is possible. Can anyone provide thoughts? The apps are mostly financial data related and do graphing, back testing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a complicated project, but if it's written in C, it's definitely *possible.* If you want some general advice, I'd google how to compile C libraries for iOS applications; you might find some success stories for libraries like libvlc or ffmpeg.

Have you tried this? https://gist.github.com/akisute/7227384

I have zero experience with ncurses, so I'm sorry I can't help any further!

Comment: Thanks. I saw this and I'll try it. My apps are C/C++.